# Display only those entries that have assets

Tags: assets, custom-field, order

I'm trying to get a list of entries that have at least one asset in it (standard assets field) called "assets".

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('banks').first.assets.filename(':notempty:').limit(2) %}
<p> {{ entry.title }} 
{% endfor %}
```

It don't show anything, no errors either.

Please advice.

Comment: Mark, I already asked this question here: ["How can I get only those entries with non-empty assets field"](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/129/125). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but none of the snippets work for me. Is my piece in the initial question wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. You do it with the `relatedTo` parameter, see the answer I accepted.