# Select all entries with asset field attribute criteria

Tags: entries, elementcriteriamodel

OK so I got entries `articles` with an asset field `documents`.
This asset field has an attribute called `docType` which is a dropdown with 5 values (A, B, C, D, E).

I d like to select all `articles` entries that have `documents` with `docType=A` criteria.

How can I dot that?
Should I make a `relatedTo` selection?
I tried multiple things but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like [explained in this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/129/125), only that you also add your dropdown field parameter to your `craft.assets` criteria model:

```
{% set assets = craft.assets.docType('A').limit(null) %}
```

and then:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('articles').relatedTo({
    targetElement: assets,
    field: 'documents'
}) %}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thx so much :)