# Get random entries, excluding an array of entry IDs, where a relational field is not empty

Tags: templating, entries, relations

I'm trying to pull a set of 3 random entries from a Section. The entries need to have a certain Assets field not empty, and I also have to exclude entries already pulled (these entries are stored in the variable `entriesA`).

The issue is that with my current query, the ID exclusion doesn't work – i.e. I'm getting back entries found in `entriesA`.

Here's how the query looks:

```
{% set entriesB = craft.entries({
    section : 'someSection',
    assetsField : ':notempty:',
    limit : 3,
    order : 'RAND()',
    id : 'and, not ' ~ entriesA.ids()|join(', not ')
}) %}
```

The problem appears to be the `assetsField : ':notempty:'` statement – when I remove that, I get no duplicates. When it's included, Craft appears to ignore the `id` parameter and I get back duplicates.

Anyone know what's up? Is it not possible to query using `:notempty:` statements *and* `id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be a bug / limitation of the `:notempty:` statement, it's probably adding its own ID criteria in the background and the merge doesn't work as expected. I'd suggest you file a bug report.

In the meantime you could just add the "not empty asset field" criteria making use of the `relatedTo` parameter as a workaround. See [How can I get only those entries with non-empty assets field](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/129/how-can-i-get-only-those-entries-with-non-empty-assets-field) for example code.

Comment: Excellent Carl, thanks. I guess I have to bite the bullet and use `relatedTo` on this one :)